# Why are the default Github repositories for React Native modules often forks?

Tags: git, react-native, github, git-fork

When I Google search for React Native modules such as [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob), often the only Github repo is a fork. With the [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) example, the only repo is the "joltup" fork. This is also the repo linked from the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob?activeTab=dependents). `https://github.com/rn-fetch-blob` (ie. without `joltup`) doesn't exist.

My understanding of forks is that they're created when a user (in this case `joltup`) wants to modify a project, so they create their fork which will then be merged into the master branch.

**What I Want To Know:**

1) Say user `joltup` wants to fork `https://github.com/rn-fetch-blob` (which again, doesn't actually exist). Their fork would then be `https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob`. Is my terminology correct that `https://github.com/rn-fetch-blob` is the fork and `https://github.com/rn-fetch-blob` is the master branch? I don't think this is correct...

2) Am I correct that the only purpose of creating a fork is to eventually merge it back into the master branch?

3) If so, why does `https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob` exist but `https://github.com/rn-fetch-blob` not exist?

Answer (score 0):

1) I think your terminology is a bit off, these aren't branches but forks:

> A fork is a copy of a repository that you manage. Forks let you make changes to a project without affecting the original repository. You can fetch updates from or submit changes to the original repository with pull requests. Any user or organization on GitHub can fork a repository.

So someone can fork repository *(A)* which then becomes a new repository *(B)*, which is a fork of *(A)*. These repositories can both have different branches, but when you fork a repository it will contain all of the branches by default.

2) Forks are often created (and in this case it seems) because the original person(s) who created the repository has gone away for whatever reason and people want to keep using it, so it becomes forked by a new maintainer. Forks can be created if someone wishes to maintain a different version of the project, the forked repository can offer up 'pull requests` to the original repository to suggest or fix changes.

3) It does exist, https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob is the original repository.